# Area of a trapezium

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given the following trapezium:
[image]
Where area of the triangle BCP is equal to 12 and $|DC|=7$, $|AB|=28$
Calculate the area of a trapezium. How to do that? as it seems that there are no sufficient data to calculate the desired area.

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

Since $\triangle{CDP}$ and $\triangle{ABP}$ are similar, we have
$$CP:AP=CD:AB=7:28=1:4.$$
Also, we have
$$[\triangle{CPB}]:[\triangle{APB}]=CP:AP=1:4.$$

Note also that $[\triangle{CPB}]=[\triangle{DPA}]$. (why?)

Comment: What's $P$?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @MPW: The intersection point between $AC$ and $BD$.

Comment: I still don't understand Can you give the answer?

Comment: @aawwwee: You can use $[\triangle{APD}]=[\triangle{DPB}]$ and $[\triangle{CDP}]:[\triangle{APD}]=CP:AP$ to get the answer.

Comment: This is not an isosceles trapezoid...

Comment: @aawwwee: I don't use the condition that $AD=BC$.